# Finding an asymptotic spectrum of an Euclidean type matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I wanted to find an asymptotic spectrum (in the limit of an infinite dimensionality) of some operator, but for simplicity I will start from a finite case, and later will take the limit.

Imagine that you have a certain operator (matrix), for which each element is a function of distance between the indeces $H_{j,k}=h(|j-k|)$, where $h(x)$ is some complex-valued function, for now it's precise form does not matter as I want to understand the procedure. The indices here are integers, and let's say $j,k$ run through $-d,-d+1,\ldots,d-1,d$ for now. I want to solve the following problem.

$$ \sum_{k} H_{j,k}\: \phi_{k}^{(\nu)} = \lambda^{(\nu)} \: \phi_{j}^{(\nu)}$$
with the following two restrictions:
$\phi_{-k} = \phi_k$, and $\phi_0 =0$. So this problem looks like an eigenvalue equations, and my goal is to understand the spectrum in the limit $d \to \infty$.

Any ideas on how to incorporate the conditions in the problem, and taking the limit?

What I did so far:

1. Brute force numerics, just picking large $d \sim 10^3$ and diagonalizing the resulting matrix, afterwards kicking out the solutions that are not symmetric $\phi_{-k}\ne\phi_k$, and that have $\phi_0\ne0$ (within some set precision). **This naive method works bad in certain cases.**
2. I tried to incorporate the second restriction by enforcing that $H_{j,0} = H_{0,k} = 0$. It is the same as saying that now $j,k$ run through $-d,\ldots,-1,1,\ldots,d$ (no zero index). Afterwards I again pick up only the solutions that are symmetric $\phi_{-j} = \phi_{j}$. This thing works better than 1), but I am not sure that this is quite correct :).

Comment: Convolution suggests Fourier

Comment: Dear @user619894, I understand you, so it technically means finding eigenfunctions in a form $\phi_j \sim e^{i \kappa j}$, right? Considering that I used the trick I described in 2), and the restrictions that I need the wavefunctions to be symmetric, it must be cosine transform.

Comment: Sounds right, it is a boundary condition issue